# Xcode9's Augmented Reality App template sandbox error

Tags: sandbox, metal, entitlements, ios11, arkit

Apple introduced its ARKit at WWDC 17 and they also added a new project template to Xcode 9 called "Augmented Reality App" which is basically supposed to be the demo app during WWDC keynote or something like that.

However, the original template itself returns a critical error during runtime, which is the following:

> libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 701 ({Your app's name}) does
>   not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT
>   appropriately entitled

What I tried so far:

1. I tried all 3 different template projects: SpriteKit, SceneKit and Metal. The error stays.
2. I created entitlements file and set "App sandbox" to true. No luck.
3. Googled the error and saw that this error is actually older (and arguably less popular) than ARKit. Sadly, nobody has found a solution yet.

Lastly, I do not think that could be relevant but I tried to run it on my iPhone 6. Has anyone managed to run AR app template? If so, how? Or anyone has any bit of information on `libMobileGestalt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/arkit/), only devices powered by A9 and higher can use `ARKit`.

> - [ARKit runs on the Apple A9 and A10 processors](https://developer.apple.com/arkit/)
> - On iOS devices with an A9 processor or later, the 
>     ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration
>     subclass provides high-precision motion tracking and enables features to help you place virtual content in relation to real-world surfaces.
> - On other devices supported by ARKit, the 
>     ARSessionConfiguration
>     base class provides basic motion tracking that permits slightly less immersive AR experiences.

The iPhone 6s and 6s plus have A9 chips, so those and all devices after that can run `ARKit`. [Found it here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_A9#Products_that_include_the_Apple_A9).

Comment: This sandbox error message is displayed before tracking session configuration is created, so they seem to be unrelated. But weirdly, `ARSessionConfiguration.isSupported` returns `false` on my iPhone6 while [it should return `true`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionconfiguration/2867255-issupported)

Comment: @MertBuran [Here](https://developer.apple.com/arkit/) I find the sentence `ARKit runs on the Apple A9 and A10 processors.` Which seems to me that it does not run on A8 or lower at all (even with the documentation above)

Comment: Apple clarified this a bit in the [WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc17/602) this afternoon. You can run an `ARSession` with `ARSessionConfiguration` on any iOS 11 device, but you don't get the full world tracking and scene understanding features that provide most of the AR magic. Those require `ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration`, which is available only on A9 and above. There's also an `arkit` device capabilities key that lets you restrict your app to only world tracking capable devices.

Comment: @rickster But even using the ARSessionConfiguration it crashes the app!

Answer (score 0):

Following iOS devices (with iOS 11 installed) are supporting ARKit:

- iPhone 6S and 6S Plus
- iPhone 7 and 7 Plus
- iPhone SE
- iPad Pro (9.7, 10.5 or 12.9)
- iPad (2017)

Here are some reference links related to ARKit Support & iOS device configurations:

[ARKit runs on the Apple A9 and A10 processors.](https://developer.apple.com/arkit/)

[iPhone Models - (Chip)](https://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/)

[iPad Models - (Chip)](https://www.apple.com/ipad/compare/)